# La función R eigen tiene un problema con las matrices simétricas

Tags: r

eigen es una función de base R que devuelve autovectores y autovalores para una matriz dada. Acabo de descubrir que no puede ser robusto para las matrices simétricas cuando especifica esto explícitamente usando symmetric=TRUE. Muestro el problema a continuación. ¿Existen bibliotecas que solucionen el problema y encuentren los autovectores correctos utilizando información sobre simetría?

### Ejemplo

En primer lugar, busquemos un vector propio para una matriz simétrica sin especificar la simetría.

```
set.seed(1)
I = 10; A = matrix( rnorm(I*I), ncol = I );
## make the matrix symmetric
A[lower.tri(A)] = A[upper.tri(A)]
ev = eigen(A, symmetric=F); ve = ev$vectors; va = ev$values;
```

Pruebe el resultado tomando la diferencia entre A aplicado a su autovector y autovector escalado por el autovalor. Debe ser un vector cero. Por tanto, la suma de sus elementos debe ser cero:

```
sum(A %*% ve[,1] - va[1]*ve[,1] )

-3.663736e-15+0i
```

Ahora, hagamos lo mismo especificando simetría:

```
ev = eigen(A, symmetric=TRUE); ve = ev$vectors; va = ev$values;
sum(A %*% ve[,1] - va[1]*ve[,1] )

-0.3534416
```

Como se mencionó en las respuestas, mi ejemplo fue malo ya que la matriz no era simétrica. El enfoque que usé para el ejemplo

```
A[lower.tri(A)] = A[upper.tri(A)]
```

realmente dará una matriz asimétrica. La forma más precisa de obtener una matriz simétrica sería

```
A[lower.tri(A)] = t(A)[lower.tri(A)]
```

o

```
A <- A+t(A)
```

Answer (score 1):

Si pretendemos que nuestra matriz no era simétrica, R parece usar otro algoritmo que da como resultado un orden de salida diferente, pero los valores propios son los mismos.

```
#?eigen


# random matrix
set.seed(1)
n = 3; 
A = matrix(rnorm(n*n), ncol = n, nrow = n)
A[lower.tri(A)] = t(A)[lower.tri(A)]

cat("symmetric matrix A\n")
A


cat("\nsymmetric = FALSE\n")
eig1 = eigen(A, symmetric = FALSE)
eig1$vectors
eig1$values
prod(eig1$values)

cat("\nsymmetric = TRUE\n")
eig2 = eigen(A, symmetric = TRUE)
eig2$vectors
eig2$values
prod(eig2$values)

cat("\nsymmetric = ...\n")
eig3 = eigen(A)
eig3$vectors
eig3$values
prod(eig3$values)
```